# Comparing data in query behave unexpectedly

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I created 2 google sheets, one contains a list of hours and the other one contain a query to that list. If I try to compare that column with another one that contains the same timings I get random results. Any idea what may cause this?

All the column are formatted as hours and the column of the query is also formatted as time

[image: COLUMN C contains =A2=B2]

Answer (score 0):

most likely this is caused by a query which converts numbers to text strings. a fix would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(Sheet1!A2:B10; "select A order by A asc", 0)*1)
```